# how can i start view pager from a custom position and can swipe back and forth from that position?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, position, adapter

how can i start view pager from a custom position and can swipe back and forth from that position in android?

```
class ImageZoom extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return storeData.dataList.size();
       // return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

       return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.zoom,container,false);
        ImageView iv= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_pg);




        iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(storeData.dataList.get(position).getPath().toString()));//

        container.addView(v);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

here view pager starts from 0 position ,, 
suppose i have 20 item and i want to start the pager from item number 10 and when i swipe back its show me item number 9 and when i swipe forward its will show item number 11,,
how can i do this?

Comment: You should override onBackPressed in activity to perform this.

Answer (score 2):

```
   yourviewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.yourviewpager);
   yourviewpager.setAdapter(youradapter);
   yourviewpager.setCurrentItem(CurrentPosition)
```

So the function your looking for is in the viewpager, not the adapter. Make sure you have enough pages